# unsuccessful booting of laptop

Tags: windows-8, boot

I have this laptop I have been trying to boot, but it has unsuccessfully responded to my efforts. I just tried booting from a live Ubuntu flash drive and below are the responses I get.

- Screen freezes here, with no visible progress, while booting Ubuntu USB: [Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmePi.jpg)

It initially had windows 8 and it hardly booted successfully with recurrent Bootloops that end in `KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED`, including others (screenshots below).  In case you have any worthwhile information on how to handle this error, I will be very thankful.

- [Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JB91L.jpg): `APC_INDEX_MISMATCH` 
   [Screenshot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wAFb.jpg): `KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED` 
   [Screenshot 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dWXE.jpg): `KERNEL_MODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED`

Comment: Since it won't boot two entirely different OSes, that's usually indicative of a hardware issue... have you ran the onboard hardware diagnostics (usually accessed from the BIOS/UEFI boot menu or from within the BIOS/UEFI settings)?.